# Prove this following inequality

Tags: inequality

Show that, for all integers m > 1,
$\frac {1}{2me}$ <  $\frac {1}{e}$ - $(1-\frac{1}{m})^m$ < $\frac {1}{me}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one part:
We have $\left(1+\frac1{km}\right)^{km}\to e$ as $k\to\infty$, hence for $k$ big enough the error in
$$ \left(1-\frac1m\right)^m\cdot e\approx\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m\left(1+\frac1{km}\right)^{km}= \left[\left(1-\frac1m\right)\left(1+\frac1{km}\right)^k\right]^m$$
becomes arbitrarily small.
Using $(1+x)^n> 1+nx$ if $x>0,n\ge2$ (Bernoulli) twice, we  get
$$ \left[\left(1-\frac1m\right)\left(1+\frac1{km}\right)^k\right]^m> \left[\left(1-\frac1m\right)\left(1+\frac1{m}\right)\right]^m=\left(1-\frac1{m^2}\right)^m>1-\frac1m.$$
Thus $\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m\cdot e>1-\frac1m$, i.e. 
$$ \frac1e-\left(1-\frac1m\right)^m<\frac1{em}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We substitute $\frac{1}{m}$ by $x$. It suffices to prove that for $0 < x \leqslant \frac{1}{2} $,
$$ \frac{x}{2e} < \frac{1}{e} - (1-x)^{\frac{1}{x}} < \frac{x}{e}. $$
It is equivalent to
$$ 1-x  < e (1-x)^{\frac{1}{x}} < 1- \frac{x}{2}.$$
These three parts are positive. By monotonicity of $\ln$,
it is equivalent to
$$ \ln (1-x)  < \ln (e (1-x)^{\frac{1}{x}}) < \ln (1- \frac{x}{2}).$$
It is equivalent to
$$ \ln (1-x)  < 1 + \frac{1}{x} \ln (1-x) < \ln (1- \frac{x}{2}).$$
To prove both sides of this inequality, we use the fact
$$ -x - x^2 < \ln (1-x) < -x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3},$$
then
$$ \ln(1-x) < -x = 1 + \frac{1}{x}(-x-x^2)< 1 + \frac{1}{x} \ln (1-x),$$
$$ 1 + \frac{1}{x} \ln (1-x) < 1 + \frac{1}{x} (-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{3}) <-\frac{x}{2} -(\frac{x}{2})^2 < \ln (1- \frac{x}{2}). $$